# NextJS 12.2 middleware upgrade, return 401 basic auth

Tags: next.js, middleware, basic-authentication

I'm trying to upgrade nextjs to v12.2+, which includes the change from using `_middleware` files on the page level to a global `middleware` file (https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide). I've also read this guide that says I can no longer return a body in my middleware: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/returning-response-body-in-middleware.

The problem I have now is that I want to show a Basic Auth prompt on specific pages, which was working in the old setup, but gives me the error "Middleware is returning a response body" in the new setup. I've tried to rewrite the code to use `NextResponse.rewrite` but that does not give me the basic auth prompt on the user's current page.

How would I rewrite this (old setup in `/admin/_middleware.js`):

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import checkBasicAuth from "@utils/middleware/checkBasicAuth";

export function middleware(req) {
  if (
    checkBasicAuth(req.headers.get("authorization"), {
      username: process.env.AUTH_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.AUTH_PASSWORD,
    })
  ) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }
  return new Response("Authentication required", {
    status: 401,
    headers: {
      "WWW-Authenticate": 'Basic realm="Secure Area"',
    },
  });
}
```

to the new middleware setup (`/src/middleware.js`) so that the user does not get redirected, and gets the basic auth prompt when not logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer myself, so for anyone stuck on the same problem, this is how I rewrote my old middleware:

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import checkBasicAuth from "@utils/middleware/checkBasicAuth";

export function middleware(request) {
  if (
    !checkBasicAuth(request.headers.get("authorization"), {
      username: process.env.AUTH_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.AUTH_PASSWORD,
    })
  ) {
    return NextResponse.rewrite(
      `${request.nextUrl.protocol}//${request.nextUrl.host}/401`,
      {
        status: 401,
        headers: {
          "WWW-Authenticate": 'Basic realm="Secure Area"',
        },
      }
    );
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

This will render but not redirect to the `/401` error page, the custom header will make sure the basic auth dialog is shown to the user.